# For loop with if/and/or statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Sub CreateDisableLists()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If _
       Range("G" & i).Value = "DSDFDFFD" And Range("I" & i).Value = "Enabled" Or _
       Range("G" & i).Value = "SFDDS" And Range("I" & i).Value = "Enabled" Or _
       Range("G" & i).Value = "FFDFDSSF" And Range("I" & i).Value = "Enabled" Or _
       Range("G" & i).Value = "FDFDSVSFD" And Range("I" & i).Value = "Enabled" Or _
       Range("G" & i).Value = "FDFDSFD" And Range("I" & i).Value = "Enabled" Or _
       Range("G" & i).Value = "GHFH" And Range("I" & i).Value = "Enabled" _
    Then
       Range("K" & i).Value = "TRUE"
    Else
       Range("K" & i).Value = "FALSE"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

How can I compress the lines between "If" and "Then" so that I loop through a list of (DSDFDFFD, SFDDS, FFDFDSSF, etc") instead of what is written above? Using this code I need to add 68 lines between "If" and "Then".

Comment: `Range("I" & i).Value = "Enabled"` check could be nested

Comment: If using multiple `Or`/`And` statements I highly recommend to use parenthesis to group them as you want them to validate.

Comment: I have updated the post. How can I use paranthesis to compress the or statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start by setting K to be FALSE, then using `If` on column I, and `Select Case` on column G:

```
Sub sCreateDisableLists()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Range("K" & i).Value = "FALSE"
        If Range("I" & i).Value = "Enabled" Then
            Select Case Range("G" & i).Value
                Case "xxx1", "xxx2", "xxx3", "xxx4", "xxx5", "xxx6"
                    Range("K" & i).Value = "TRUE"
            End Select
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If using multiple `Or`/`And` statements I highly recommend to use parenthesis to group them as you want them to validate, or you might not get the result you expect.

Your `If` statement could be like:

```
Dim Arr() As Variant
Arr = Array("DSDFDFFD", "SFDDS", "FFDFDSSF") 'define your keys here

If Range("I" & i).Value = "Enabled" And IsInArray(Range("I" & i).Value, Arr) Then
    Range("K" & i).Value = "TRUE"
Else
    Range("K" & i).Value = "FALSE"
End If
```

or even less:

```
Dim Arr() As Variant
Arr = Array("DSDFDFFD", "SFDDS", "FFDFDSSF") 'define your keys here

Range("K" & i).Value = UCase(Range("I" & i).Value = "Enabled" And IsInArray(Range("I" & i).Value, Arr))
```

---

using this function

```
Public Function IsInArray(ByVal stringToBeFound As String, ByVal Arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(Arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the post as it was not precise enough. How can I compress the or statements when there is now logical conncetive between the strings in the or statement?

Comment: @It_hurts_when_ip I have updated my answer so it fits your post. Have a look again. I condensed your `If` statement to only 3 lines (and a useful function).

Answer (score 0):

Not very much to be improved, but the next code would be a little more compact:

```
Sub testImproveCode()
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim j As Long, boolOk As Boolean
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        For j = 1 To 6
            If Range("G" & i).value = "xxx" & j And _
                   Range("I" & i).value = "Enable" Then
                boolOk = True: Exit For
        Next j
        If boolOk Then
             Range("K" & i).value = "TRUE": boolOk = False
        Else
             Range("K" & i).value = "FALSE"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the post as it was not precise enough. How can I compress the or statements when there is now logical conncetive between the strings in the or statement?

Comment: @It_hurts_when_ip: Then,  you can use an array keeping all your strings to be checked...

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateDisableLists()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, y As Long
    Dim strValues As String: strValues = "DSDFDFFD,SFDDS,FFDFDSSF,FDFDSVSFD,FDFDSFD,GHFH"
    Dim strIvalue As String: strIvalue = "Enabled"
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim BooleanStatus As Boolean

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

        arr = Split(strValues, ",")

        For i = 2 To LastRow

            BooleanStatus = False

            For y = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

                If (.Range("G" & i).Value = arr(y)) And .Range("I" & i).Value = strIvalue Then
                    BooleanStatus = True
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next y

            If BooleanStatus = True Then
                .Range("K" & i).Value = "TRUE"
            Else
                .Range("K" & i).Value = "FALSE"
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```